# Plot a pandas categorical Series with Seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I would like to plot the result of the `values_counts()` method with `seaborn`, but when I do so, it only shows one of the variables.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['b','b','a','c','c','c'],"B":['a','a','a','c','b','d']})
counts = df.A.value_counts()
sns.barplot(counts)
```

[image: Result of above code]

I want a barplot showing heights of `'a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3`

I've tried renaming the index and passing in `x` and `y` parameters, but I cant' get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
# Sorting indices so it's easier to read 
counts.sort_index(inplace=True)

sns.barplot(x = counts.index, y = counts)
plt.ylabel('counts')
```

[image]

Note that using `pandas.Series.plot` gives a *very* similar plot: `counts.plot('bar')` or `counts.plot.bar()`

Comment: Probably a good idea to go ahead and sort count by index first.  `count=count.sort_index()` to get that x-axis in more logical easy to follow order.

Comment: @ScottBoston, I was litterally *just* doing that when you posted that comment!